# why a method has to be generic when passing a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

For example i have this C# method :

```
public static int Count<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{         
     return 0;
}
```

Why i have to write `Count<T>` rather than `Count` even when i'm not using the `T` type inside the method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't *have* to. You could go entirely non-generic:

```
public static int Count(IEnumerable sequence)
{         
     return 0;
}
```

And since [`IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx), this will work for all sequences.

One reason not to do this, however, is that if you plan to do:

```
int count = 0;
foreach(var obj in sequence) count++;
return count;
```

then the *non-generic* version when used with *value types* will **box every value** - increasing allocations. The generic version will not do any boxing.

Comment: I know that your suggestion is a good solution , but i'm not asking for a solution , in fact why it is mandatory in C# to write a generic method when passing generic Type ?

Comment: (re now-deleted comment) it isn't :) I could write `public static int Count(IEnumerable<int> sequence)`, which a non-generic method that accepts a generic type. The problem is that you want it to be used with *any* generic type in that family - i.e. `IEnumerable<T>`. Now: what does that `T` mean? is that the `T` from a generic type definition somewhere in the hierarchy? or is that a new `T` that only applies to this method? what constraints apply to that `T`? all of these things are **defined** (in this case) by the `<T>` in the method signature

Comment: Thanks for your response , but i'm not asking for a solution in fact i just want to know why in C# it is mandatory to write a generic method when the parameter is generic even when we are not using the T parameter...

Comment: @KhalilLazhar (see also the comment above) the caller still needs to know how to call it, and what inputs it can accept... (dammit! please stop deleting comments when people are trying to reply to them :p)

Comment: Thanks Mr Gravell. Now it is clear. ( Sorry for deleting them :p )

Comment: No possibility for getting back the deleted comments ? :(

Comment: @KhalilLazhar I can if you want (the perks of the ♦) - I don't tend to undelete without an explicit request

Comment: Yes i want Mr Marc

Comment: @KhalilLazhar I've undeleted them

Comment: Thanks again Mr Marc .